# Understanding RequireJS: What exactly is passed to the anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to wrap my head around using RequireJS for my web projects.

For testing, I've written two mini functions:

**multiply.js**

```
;function multiply(x, y) {
    return parseInt(x) * parseInt(y);
}
```

**substract.js**

```
;function substract(x, y) {
    return parseInt(x) - parseInt(y);
}
```

Everything loads flawlessly, so I am definitely on the right track, but there are still some things I don't understand.

**main.js** looks like this:

```
define(['substract', 'multiply'], function(one, two) {
    console.log('substract(8, "4") --> ' + substract(8, "4"));
    console.log('multiply(10, 10) --> ' + multiply(10, 10));
});
```

The functions all work, but `alert(typeof(one));` tells me it's undefined.

I know this question is probably pretty basic, but why is it undefined & what is passed to the anonymous function?

Comment: Where did your "add" function go in your last edit, and why do you have three parameters on that function in your `define` instead of two?

Comment: You will need to declare those two functions as require modules. Currently, you're just defining global functions.

Comment: I removed the `add` function because it doesn't add any value to the question, just makes it longer. Of course I shouldn't add any code error when editing, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing a number of things wrong.

First of all, you need to declare `multiply` and `subtract` as *RequireJS modules*, like this:

```
define(function () {
    return function multiply(a, b) {
        return parseInt(x) * parseInt(y);
    };
});
```

Do the same thing for your other modules you want to declare. Then, write your app module like this:

```
define(['subtract', 'multiply'], function(subtract, multiply) {
    console.log('subtract(8, "4") --> ' + subtract(8, "4"));
    console.log('multiply(10, 10) --> ' + multiply(10, 10));
});
```

Note that the modules you declared above will be *injected* into the app function as parameters. You can then use the module return values through those parameters.

Yes, the code you have works, but it doesn't use RequireJS properly. It simply defines `multiply` and `subtract` *globally*, not as modules. Part of the purpose of RequireJS is to collect your code into modules that don't pollute the global namespace.

---

Note: I corrected your spelling mistake, and I converted all instances of "substract" to "subtract".

Comment: Whoah, now I got it! Thank you!